# Access the properties of an element in an XML drawable resource

Tags: android-layout, android

Excuse the title - not sure how to word this question.

I created a file called `rectangle.xml` inside `res/drawable`.  It is an extremely basic rectangle shape, the I'm using with an ImageView within a custom listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
   <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

Using it like so:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_colorRect"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/rectangle" />
```

I want to be able to access that rectangle's `solid` property so I can change its color on the fly.  I can't access that property through the ImageView .. so I imagine I have to somehow dig into the children of the ImageView, find the shape, and change it that way.

How do I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I never done this but what you could try is create two different shapes with separate properties and then programmatically change the source of ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it and I managed to do it.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.row_colorRect);
((GradientDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).setColor(Color.RED);
```

Accessing the `ImageView` `GradientDrawable`, that represents your `rectangle.xml` resource, you can change its solid color, among other attributes.

Comment: This worked wonderfully, thank you.  Am I approaching this wrong?  I just want colored indicators on each of my ListView rows, and I want to be able to change their colors based on the "status" of the row.  But everyone who has replied seems to have never attempted such a thing.. makes me think I'm doing this in an unusual way.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**shape.xml (Drawable)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GradientDrawable sd = (GradientDrawable) imageView.getBackground().mutate();
                sd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CCC111"));
                sd.invalidateSelf();
            }
        });
    }

}
```